# Trying to implement saveData() and deleteData() they using an Array

Tags: java

`SaveData()` and `deleteData()` are in my studentList class. I'm trying to call them in my UI but they are not working as expected.

I do have a Student class too. Any good idea?

```
// This is in my UI for my Save and delete button
        //add actionListener to SaveData
         saveData.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                 theList.saveData();
             }
         });


         //add actionListener to DeleteData

         deleteData.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                 theList.deleteData();
             }
         });
//saveData()in the StudentList Class

 public void saveData() {
        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("StudentData.dat");
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
            out.writeInt(numberOfStudents);

            writeStudentsToFile(out);
            out.close();
            fileOut.close();
        } catch ( IOException i ) {
            i.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void writeStudentsToFile(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {

        for ( int i = 0; i < numberOfStudents; i++ ) {

            out.writeObject(studentListArray[i]);
        }

    }

//deletData() in the StudentList Class
public Student[] deleteData (String firstName)  
{     

    for(int i = 0; i<studentListArray.length; i++)  
    {  
        if(studentListArray[i].getFirstName().equals(firstName))  
        {  
        numberOfStudents++;  
        }  
    }         
    Student[] studentNewListArray = new Student[studentListArray.length-numberOfStudents];  

    for(int i = 0; i<studentNewListArray.length; i++)  
    {  

        if(studentListArray[i].getFirstName().equals(firstName)|| studentNewListArray[i].getFirstName().equals(null))  
        {         
            studentNewListArray[i] = studentListArray[i+1];  
            studentListArray[i+1] = null;  
        }  
        else  
        {  
            studentNewListArray[i] = studentListArray[i] ;   
        }  
    }  
    return studentNewListArray;  
}
```

Comment: Quick question why are you not using array list the removing & saving would be super easy ...

Comment: Instructor said NOT to use arrayList please!

Comment: Paste all your code can tell you what is wrong ...

Comment: okay I will do that shortly

Comment: One of the problem is when you do save data it over write the existing data ... so when you load the program you have to read from the file and populate your array else you will keep loosing data... As for delete your logic is not correct will post a sudo code ... in a bit ...

Comment: okay... thanks.. I can't post my code as of now. The System does not allow. I will be waiting for you sudo code then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For deletign do something like this ...

```
public Student[] deleteData (String firstName)  {
    for(int counter=0;counter< studentListArray.length;counter++){
         if(studentListArray[counter].getFirstName().equals(firstName)){
               for(int counter1= counter;counter< studentListArray.length-1;counter1++){
                    studentListArray[counter1]=studentListArray[counter1 +1];
               }
               studentListArray[counter1+1]=null;
               break;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please How int counter1; is different from the int counter; I assume that counter in my case is int numberOfStudents; right?

Comment: consider a case say there as 10 elements in the array & you want to delete 5 element so the counter will take you to the 5 element and then the counter1 loop will move the 6 element to the 5 elements place and the last one will become null ...

Comment: Hum! smart... got it!

Comment: It works. thank you so much.. I gonna try if I can post the code for you to take a look at the savaData() part please!